# knex insert json array as distinct records

Tags: node.js, sql-server, knex.js

I'm having the following json object that I need to insert into my sql server tables (activity & marketing). The participant list is an array of email addresses found inside the marketing object should be inserted as a separate row with differing participant email addresses. Like this, I have an array of a bunch of json objects. What knex query could I possibly use to insert this record into my database?

```
{
    "activity": {
        "activityType": "Marketing",
        "activityDate": "2020-07-19",
        "activityStartTime": "2020-07-19 03:27:45.000",
        "activityEndTime": "2020-07-19 04:27:45.000",
        "activityUrl": "https://www.sdss.com",
        "isPublished": false,
        "activityDuration": 30,
        "eventId": "03361624-3964-4f2e-9ab0-34ea48027f09",
        "activityName": "Customer Delight"
    },
"marketing": {
        "Name": "sales booster",
        "meetingUrl": "http://www.zzz.com",
        "clientViewName": "sales boost",
        "linkOneName": "test1",
        "linkTwoName": "test2",
        "linkOneNameUrl": "www.gggg.com",
        "linkTwoNameUrl": "www.gggg.com",
        "participants": [
        {
            "email": "bbb@bbb.com"
        },
        {
            "email": "aaa@aaa.com"
        },
        {
            "email": "ccc@ccc.com"
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the desired object to be inserted as a row into db?  Add it to your question please.

Comment: @Molda the desired object is the json itself. The activity object should be inserted into my activity table and the marketing object to the marketing table. However, for marketing table it's not as straightforward as it looks. Since I have multiple participants, i should have a separate marketing object record in the marketing table for each participant. All I'm looking for is a knex query to make this happen

Comment: I doubt it knex can help you with that. Specialy because it's quite simple to iterate over marketing.participants using a loop and insert the object for each of the participants.

Comment: @Molda Well, I'm already using that approach but it does not scale. When I have several marketing groups each with multiple participants, I'll have to make multiple queries to the db which is having significant performance issues

Comment: You can insert multiple rows at once by passing an array of objects to insert function, you just need to prepare the data. So create new array and push the objects in it. Then insert it like this `knex('marketing').insert(the_array_of_objects)`

Comment: @Molda Again, that approach doesn't work either as my writes affect multiple tables. From the json array, I have no way of identifying which object belongs to which table.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried to your question. It's impossible to help you without seeing what you tried. It doesn't matter how many tables it affects. You insert into each table separately. What `json array` are you talking about. I only see one array  `marketing.participants`. Make sure to add as many details to your question as possible.